# How do I get setup.py test to use a specific fortran compiler?

Tags: python, fortran, setuptools, distutils

I am trying to test a [package](https://github.com/jsalvatier/scikits.bvp_solver) that includes some f90 files. If I build or install and specify the fortran compiler, it works fine. However, when I try to test I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\jsalvatier\workspace\scikits.bvp_solver>python setup.py config_fc --fcompiler=gfortran test
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running test
running egg_info
running build_src
build_src
building extension "scikits.bvp_solver.bvp_solverf" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build\src.win32-2.6\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build\src.win32-2.6' to include_dirs.
  adding 'build\src.win32-2.6\scikits\bvp_solver\lib\bvp_solverf-f2pywrappers2.f90' to sources.
building data_files sources
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
writing scikits.bvp_solver.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing namespace_packages to scikits.bvp_solver.egg-info\namespace_packages.txt
writing top-level names to scikits.bvp_solver.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to scikits.bvp_solver.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'scikits.bvp_solver.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'scikits.bvp_solver.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
customize Mingw32CCompiler
customize Mingw32CCompiler using build_ext
customize GnuFCompiler
Found executable C:\mingw\bin\g77.exe
gnu: no Fortran 90 compiler found
gnu: no Fortran 90 compiler found
Found executable C:\mingw\bin\g77.exe
customize GnuFCompiler
gnu: no Fortran 90 compiler found
gnu: no Fortran 90 compiler found
customize GnuFCompiler using build_ext
building 'scikits.bvp_solver.bvp_solverf' extension
compiling C sources
C compiler: gcc -mno-cygwin -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes

compile options: '-Ibuild\src.win32-2.6 -IC:\Python26\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python26\include -IC:\Python26\PC -c'
gcc -mno-cygwin -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Ibuild\src.win32-2.6 -IC:\Python26\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python26\include -IC:\Python26\PC -c build\src.win32-2.6\scikits\bvp_solver\lib\bvp_solverfmodule.c -o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\build\src.win32-2.6\scikits\bvp_solver\lib\bvp_solverfmodule.o
Found executable C:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe
gcc -mno-cygwin -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Ibuild\src.win32-2.6 -IC:\Python26\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python26\include -IC:\Python26\PC -c build\src.win32-2.6\fortranobject.c -o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\build\src.win32-2.6\fortranobject.o
compiling Fortran 90 module sources
XXX: module_build_dir='build\\temp.win32-2.6\\Release\\scikits\\bvp_solver' option ignored
XXX: Fix module_dir_switch for  GnuFCompiler
XXX: module_dirs=[] option ignored
XXX: Fix module_include_switch for  GnuFCompiler
Fortran f77 compiler: C:\mingw\bin\g77.exe -g -Wall -fno-second-underscore -mno-cygwin -O3 -funroll-loops
compile options: '-Ibuild\src.win32-2.6 -IC:\Python26\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python26\include -IC:\Python26\PC -c'
error: f90 not supported by GnuFCompiler needed for scikits\bvp_solver\lib\BVP_M.f90
```

Is there a way to work around this? I'm on windows 7, python 2.6, numpy 1.4.1.

Comment: Are you using gfortran or g95? Also, where is the F90 compiler installed?

Comment: I am using gfortran, though I could install g95. gfortran is installed in C:\MinGW\bin

Comment: I'd recommend sticking with gfortran. I just wanted to make sure you were really using gfortran; people often get g95 and gfortran confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that the 'test' command requires building inplace.

```
python setup.py config --fcompiler=gfortran build_ext --inplace
```

was generating the same error as before, but

```
python setup.py config --fcompiler=gfortran build_ext
```

was not.

I was able to work around the problem by

1. Running setup in interactive
   mode(python setup.py)
2. Setting the fortran compiler to gfortran
3. selecting inplace build (3)

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://packages.python.org/scikits.bvp_solver/) for that package recommends building as follows:

```
python setup.py config --compiler=mingw32 build --compiler=mingw32 install
```

That's supposed to work with the mingw32 version of gfortran. I don't have a Windows machine accessible, but when I've built other Python modules (numpy, for example) with gfortran, the command was something like:

```
python setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95
```

ETA: I misread the beginning of your question, and now I see that you can build but not test. Have you tried this with only "--compiler=mingw32"?

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. Interestingly, python setup.py config --fcompiler=gfortran build_ext --inplace didn't work, but python setup.py config --fcompiler=gfortran build_ext does, I think this may be the root of the problem as I think 'test' has to build inplace.

Comment: That python setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95 works perfectly to install scipy in ubuntu 11.10. I was searching the whole day and this was my solution.