# Cython and fortran - how to compile together without f2py

Tags: python, c, fortran, cython, distutils

**FINAL UPDATE**

This question is about how to write a `setup.py` that will compile a cython module which accesses FORTRAN code directly, like C would. It was a rather long and arduous journey to the solution, but the full mess is included below for context.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I have an extension which is a Cython file, which sets up some heap memory and passes it to the fortran code, and a fortran file, which is a venerable old module that I'd like to avoid reimplementing if I can.

The `.pyx` file compiles fine to C, but the cython compiler chokes on the `.f90` file with the following error:

```bsh
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
cythoning delaunay/__init__.pyx to delaunay/__init__.c
building 'delaunay' extension
error: unknown file type '.f90' (from 'delaunay/stripack.f90')
```

Here's (the top half of) my setup file:

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
  Extension("delaunay",
    sources=["delaunay/__init__.pyx",
             "delaunay/stripack.f90"])
]

setup(
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules,
  ...
)
```

*NOTE: I originally had the fortran file's location incorrectly specified (without the directory prefix) but this breaks in exactly the same way after I fixed that.*

**Things I have tried:**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523767/how-do-i-get-setup-py-test-to-use-a-specific-fortran-compiler), and tried passing in the name of the fortran compiler (i.e. gfortran) like this:

```bsh
$ python setup.py config --fcompiler=gfortran build_ext --inplace
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: option --fcompiler not recognized
```

And I've also tried removing `--inplace`, in case that was the problem (it wasn't, same as the top error message).

So, how do I compile this fortran? Can I hack it into a `.o` myself and get away with linking it? Or [is this a bug in Cython](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cython-users/DP_FksDi6iM), which will force me to reimplement distutils or hack around with the preprocessor?

**UPDATE**

So, having checked out the `numpy.distutils` packages, I understand the problem a bit more. It seems that you have to

1. Use cython to convert the .pyx files to cpython .c files,
2. Then use an `Extension`/`setup()` combination that supports fortran, like `numpy`'s.

Having tried this, my `setup.py` now looks like this:

```
from numpy.distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from numpy.distutils.extension import Extension

cy_modules = cythonize('delaunay/sphere.pyx')
e = cy_modules[0]

ext_modules = [
  Extension("delaunay.sphere",
      sources=e.sources + ['delaunay/stripack.f90'])
]

setup(
  ext_modules = ext_modules,
  name="delaunay",
  ...
)
```

(note that I've also restructured the module a bit, since seemingly an `__init__.pyx` is disallowed...)

Now is where things become buggy and platform-dependent. I have two testing systems available - one Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard), using Macports Python 2.7, and one Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) using the system python 2.7.

On Snow Leopard, the following applies:

This means that the module compiles (hurray!) (although there's no `--inplace` for numpy, it seems, so I had to system-wide install the testing module :/) but I still get a crash on `import` as follows:

```
  >>> import delaunay
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<snip>site-packages/delaunay/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
      from sphere import delaunay_mesh
  ImportError: dlopen(<snip>site-packages/delaunay/sphere.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    <snip>site-packages/delaunay/sphere.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

and on Lion, I get a compile error, following a rather confusing looking compile line:

```
gfortran:f77: build/src.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/delaunay/sphere-f2pywrappers.f
/usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -arch i686 -arch x86_64 -Wall -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/delaunay/sphere.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/delaunay/spheremodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/fortranobject.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/delaunay/stripack.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/delaunay/sphere-f2pywrappers.o -lgfortran -o build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/delaunay/sphere.so
ld: duplicate symbol _initsphere in build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/delaunay/spheremodule.o ldand :build /temp.macosx-10.7-intelduplicate- 2.7symbol/ delaunay/sphere.o _initsphere in forbuild architecture /i386
temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/delaunay/spheremodule.o and build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/delaunay/sphere.o for architecture x86_64
```

Now let's just step back a moment before we pore over the details here. Firstly, I know there are a bunch of headaches over architecture clashes in 64-bit Mac OS X; I had to work very hard to get Macports Python working on the Snow Leopard machine (just to upgrade from system python 2.6). I also know that when you see `gfortran -arch i686 -arch x86_64` you are sending mixed messages to your compiler. There are all manner of platform-specific problems buried in there, that we don't need to worry about in the context of this question.

*But let's just look at this line*:
`gfortran:f77: build/src.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/delaunay/sphere-f2pywrappers.f`

**what is numpy doing?!** I don't need any f2py features in this build! I actually wrote a cython module *in order to avoid* dealing with f2py's insanity (I need to have 4 or 5 output variables, as well as neither-in-nor-out arguments - neither of which is well supported in f2py.) I just want it to compile `.c` -> `.o`, and `.f90` -> `.o` and link them. I could write this compiler line myself if I knew how to include all the relevant headers.

Please tell me I don't need to write my own makefile for this... or that there's a way to translate fortran to (output-compatible) C so I can just avoid python ever seeing the .f90 extension (which fixes the whole problem.) Note that [`f2c`](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/) is not suitable for this as it only works on F77 and this is a more modern dialect (hence the `.f90` file extension).

**UPDATE 2**
The following bash script will happily compile and link the code in place:

```bsh
PYTHON_H_LOCATION="/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/"

cython sphere.pyx

gcc -arch x86_64 -c sphere.c -I$PYTHON_H_LOCATION
gfortran -arch x86_64 -c stripack.f90
gfortran -arch x86_64 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/opt/local/lib *.o -o sphere.so
```

Any advice on how to make this kind of hack compatible with a setup.py? I don't anyone installing this module to have to go find `Python.h` manually...

Comment: Fortran support seems to come from `numpy`. Perhaps you can import [`numpy.distutils.extension.Extension`](http://www.scipy.org/doc/numpy_api_docs/numpy.distutils.extension.html) instead of `distutils.core.Extension`.

Comment: Also read the [NumPy Distutils Users Guide](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/DISTUTILS.rst.txt) and the [packaging reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/distutils.html).

Comment: Do you have gfortran installed at all? You really need some Fortran compiler, it's really necessary.

Comment: @Vladimir F - gfortran is definitely installed.

Comment: @MvG - thanks, I am looking into that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I've created a project on github which wraps up this generating of compile lines by hand. it's called [complicated_build](https://github.com/joe-jordan/complicated_build).

**UPDATE 2:** in fact, "generating by hand" is a really bad idea as it's platform specific — the project now reads the values from the `distutils.sysconfig` module, which is the settings used to compile python (i.e. exactly what we want,) the only setting which is guessed is fortran compiler and file extensions (which are user-configurable). I suspect it is reimplementing a fair bit of distutils now!

---

The way to do this is to write your own compiler lines, and hack them into your `setup.py`. I show an example below which works for my (very simple) case, which has the following strucutre:

- imports
- `cythonize()` any `.pyx` files, so you only have fortran and C files.
- define a `build()` function which compiles your code:

  - maybe some easy-to-change constants, like compiler names and architecture
  - list up the fortran and C files
  - generate the shell commands that will build the modules
  - add the linker line
  - run the shell commands.
- if the command was `install` and the target doesn't exist yet, build it.
- run setup (which will build the pure python sections)
- if the command was `build`, run the build now.

my implementation of this is shown below. It's designed for only one extension module, and it recompiles all the files every time, so may require further extension to be of more general use. Also note that I've hard coded various unix `/`s, so if you're porting this to windows make sure you adapt or replace with `os.path.sep`.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import sys, os, shutil

cythonize('delaunay/sphere.pyx')

target = 'build/lib/delaunay/sphere.so'

def build():
  fortran_compiler = 'gfortran'
  c_compiler = 'gcc'
  architecture = 'x86_64'
  python_h_location = get_python_inc()
  build_temp = 'build/custom_temp'
  global target

  try:
    shutil.rmtree(build_temp)
  except OSError:
    pass

  os.makedirs(build_temp) # if you get an error here, please ensure the build/ ...
  # folder is writable by this user.

  c_files = ['delaunay/sphere.c']
  fortran_files = ['delaunay/stripack.f90']

  c_compile_commands = []

  for cf in c_files:
    # use the path (sans /s), without the extension, as the object file name:
    components = os.path.split(cf)
    name = components[0].replace('/', '') + '.'.join(components[1].split('.')[:-1])
    c_compile_commands.append(
      c_compiler + ' -arch ' + architecture + ' -I' + python_h_location + ' -o ' +
      build_temp + '/' + name + '.o -c ' + cf
    )

  fortran_compile_commands = []

  for ff in fortran_files:
    # prefix with f in case of name collisions with c files:
    components = os.path.split(ff)
    name = components[0].replace('/', '') + 'f' + '.'.join(components[1].split('.')[:-1])
    fortran_compile_commands.append(
      fortran_compiler + ' -arch ' + architecture + ' -o ' + build_temp + 
      '/' + name + '.o -c ' + ff
    )

  commands = c_compile_commands + fortran_compile_commands + [
    fortran_compiler + ' -arch ' + architecture + 
    ' -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup ' + build_temp + '/*.o -o ' + target
  ]

  for c in commands:
    os.system(c)


if 'install' in sys.argv and not os.path.exists(target):
  try:
    os.makedirs('build/lib/delaunay')
  except OSError:
    # we don't care if the containing folder already exists.
    pass
  build()

setup(
  name="delaunay",
  version="0.1",
  ...
  packages=["delaunay"]
)

if 'build' in sys.argv:
  build()
```

This could be wrapped up into a new `Extension` class I guess, with it's own `build_ext` command - an exercise for the advanced student ;)

Answer (score 2):

Simply build and install your vintage Fortran library outside of Python, then link to it in distutils. Your question indicates that you do not intend to temper with this library, so a once-and-for-all install will probably do (using the library's build and installation instructions). Then link the Python extension to the installed external library:

```
ext_modules = [
    Extension("delaunay",
              sources = ["delaunay/__init__.pyx"],
              libraries = ["delaunay"])
]
```

This approach is also safe for the case that you realize that you need wrappers for other languages as well, such as Matlab, Octave, IDL, ...

**Update**

At some point, if you end up with more than a few such external libraries that you want to wrap, it is advantageous to add a top-level build system that installs all these libraries, and manages the building of all the wrappers as well. I have `cmake` for this purpose, which is great at handling system-wide builds and installations. However, it cannot build Python stuff out of the box, but it *can* be taught easily to call "python setup.py install" in each subdirectory `python`, thus invoking distutils. So the overall build process looks like this:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
make install
make python
(make octave)
(make matlab)
```

It is very important to always separate core library code from wrappers for specific front-end languages (also for your own projects!), since they tend to change rather fast. What happens otherwise can be seen at the example of `numpy`: Instead of writing one general-purpose C library `libndarray.so` and creating thin wrappers for Python, there are Python C API calls *everywhere* in the sources. This is what is now holding back `Pypy` as a serious alternative to CPython, since in order to get `numpy` they have to support every last bit of the CPython API, which they can't do, since they have a just-in-time compiler and a different garbage collector. This means we are missing out on a lot of potential improvements.

Bottom line:

1. Build general purpose Fortran/C libraries separately and install them system-wide.
2. Have a separate build step for the wrappers, which should be kept as lightweight as possible, so that it's easy to adapt for the next big language X that comes about. If there is one safe assumption, it is that X will support linking with C libraries.

Comment: that is a very elegant solution - well done! I'll see if I can get it working, and change the "correct" answer if I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the object file outside of `distutils` then include it at the linking step using the `extra_objects` argument to Extension's constructor. In `setup.py`:

```
...
e = Extension(..., extra_objects = ['holycode.o'])
...
```

On the command prompt:

```
# gfortran -c -fPIC holycode.f
# ./setup.py build_ext ...
```

With only one external object, this will be the easiest way for many.