# my c++ extension behaves differently with faulthandler

Tags: c++, python, cython

**Background**

I have a C++ extension which runs a 3D watershed pass on a buffer. It's got a nice Cython wrapper to initialise a massive buffer of `signed char`s to represent the voxels. I initialise some native data structures in python (in a compiled cython file) and then call one C++ function to initialise the buffer, and another to actually run the algorithm (I could have written these in Cython too, but I'd like it to work as a C++ library as well without a python.h dependancy.)

**Weirdness**

I'm in the process of debugging my code, trying different image sizes to gauge RAM usage and speed, etc, and I've noticed something very strange about the results - they change depending on whether I use `python test.py` (specifically `/usr/bin/python` on Mac OS X 10.7.5/Lion, which is python 2.7) or `python` and running `import test`, and calling a function on it (and indeed, on my laptop (OS X 10.6.latest, with macports python 2.7) the results are also deterministically different - each platform/situation is different, but each one is always the same as itself.). In all cases, the same function is called, loads some input data from a file, and runs the C++ module.

*A note on 64-bit python - I am not using distutils to compile this code, but something akin to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12706377/393816) (i.e. with an explicit `-arch x86_64` call). This shouldn't mean anything, and all my processes in Activity Monitor are called `Intel (64-bit)`.*

As you may know, the point of watershed is to find objects in the pixel soup - in 2D it's often used on photos. Here, I'm using it to find lumps in 3D in much the same way - I start with some lumps ("grains") in the image and I want to find the inverse lumps ("cells") in the space between them.

The way the results change is that I literally find a different number of lumps. For exactly the same input data:

`python test.py`:

```
grain count: 1434
seemed to have 8000000 voxels, with average value 0.8398655
find cells:
running watershed algorithm...
found 1242 cells from 1434 original grains!
...
```

however,

`python`, `import test`, `test.run()`:

```
grain count: 1434
seemed to have 8000000 voxels, with average value 0.8398655
find cells:
running watershed algorithm...
found 927 cells from 1434 original grains!
...
```

This is the same in the interactive python shell and `bpython`, which I originally thought was to blame.

Note the "average value" number is exactly the same - this indicates that the same fraction of voxels have initially been marked as in the problem space - i.e. that my input file was initialised in (very very probably) exactly the same way both times in voxel-space.

Also note that no part of the algorithm is non-deterministic; there are no random numbers or approximations; subject to floating point error (which should be the same each time) we should be performing exactly the same computations on exactly the same numbers both times. Watershed runs using a big buffer of integers (here `signed char`s) and the results are counting clusters of those integers, all of which is implemented in one big C++ call.

I have tested the `__file__` attribute of the relevant module objects (which are themselves attributes of the imported `test`), and they're pointing to the same installed `watershed.so` in my system's `site-packages`.

**Questions**

I don't even know where to begin debugging this - how is it possible to call the same function with the same input data and get different results? - what about interactive python might cause this (e.g. by changing the way the data is initialised)? - Which parts of the (rather large) codebase are relevant to these questions?

In my experience it's much more useful to post ALL the code in a stackoverflow question, and not assume you know where the problem is. However, that is thousands of lines of code here, and I have literally no idea where to start! I'm happy to post small snippets on request.

I'm also happy to hear debugging strategies - interpreter state that I can check, details about the way python might affect an imported C++ binary, and so on.

Here's the structure of the code:

```
project/
  clibs/
    custom_types/
      adjacency.cpp (and hpp)     << graph adjacency (2nd pass; irrelevant = irr)
     *array.c (and h)             << dynamic array of void*s
     *bit_vector.c (and h)        << int* as bitfield with helper functions
      polyhedron.cpp (and hpp)    << for voxel initialisation; convex hull result
      smallest_ints.cpp (and hpp) << for voxel entity affiliation tracking (irr)
    custom_types.cpp (and hpp)    << wraps all files in custom_types/
    delaunay.cpp (and hpp)        << marshals calls to stripack.f90
   *stripack.f90 (and h)          << for computing the convex hulls of grains
    tensors/
     *D3Vector.cpp (and hpp)      << 3D double vector impl with operators
    watershed.cpp (and hpp)       << main algorithm entry points (ini, +two passes)
  pywat/
    __init__.py
    watershed.pyx                 << cython class, python entry points.
    geometric_graph.py            << python code for post processing (irr)
  setup.py                        << compile and install directives
  test/
    test.py                       << entry point for testing installed lib
```

(files marked `*` have been used extensively in other projects and are very well tested, those suffixed `irr` contain code only run *after* the problem has been caused.)

**Details**

as requested, the main stanza in `test/test.py`:

```
testfile = 'valid_filename'

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # handles segfaults...
  import faulthandler
  faulthandler.enable()
  run(testfile)
```

and my interactive invocation looks like:

```
import test
test.run(test.testfile)
```

**Clues**

when I run this at the straight interpreter:

```
import faulthandler
faulthandler.enable()
import test
test.run(test.testfile)
```

I get the results from the file invocation (i.e. 1242 cells), although when I run it in bpython, it just crashes.

This is clearly the source of the problem - hats off to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams for asking the right question straight away.

**UPDATE:**

I've [opened a bug on the faulthandler github](https://github.com/haypo/faulthandler/issues/4) and I'm working towards a solution. If I find something that people can learn from I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Does the main stanza strictly call `run()`?

Comment: nearly. added the exact code for both cases.

Comment: see my follow up edit - the call to `faulthandler.enable()` appears to make a difference! I'll go digging in it's source [here](https://github.com/haypo/faulthandler) for answers.

Comment: Does any of your cython code import the `test` module to access its contents?

Comment: @Blckknght no, the test module is entirely dependent - it is simulating a user of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging this application extensively (`printf()`ing out all the data at multiple points during the run, piping outputs to log files, `diff`ing the log files) I found what seemed to cause the strange behaviour.

**I was using uninitialised memory** in a couple of places, and (for some bizarre reason) this gave me repeatable behaviour differences between the two cases I describe above - one without `faulthandler` and one with.

Incidentally, this is also why the bug *disappeared* from one machine but continued to manifest itself on another, part way through debugging (which really should have given me a clue!)

My mistake here was to assume things about the problem based on a spurious correlation - in theory the garbage ram should have been differently random each time I accessed it (ahh, theory.) In this case I would have been quicker finding the problem with a printout of the main calculation function and a [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

So, as usual, the answer is **the bug is not in the library, it is somewhere in your code** - in this case, it was my fault for `malloc()`ing a chunk of RAM, falsely assuming that other parts of my code were going to initialise it (which they only did sometimes.)