# Wrapping a f2py-compiled Fortran .so with Cython (without passing by python)

Tags: python, cython, f2py

Looking at some other similar questions ([Cython and fortran - how to compile together without f2py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696520/cython-and-fortran-how-to-compile-together-without-f2py)), I may be going about this the wrong way, but the workflow I'd like to put in place seems so cythonic/pythonic that I would be surprised if the following isn't possible:

1) Compile a fortran_func.so with f2py from the fortran_func.f source file that contains the foo subroutine I need. Seeing as I have the .f source, I do know the correct function call syntax.

2) Magic step perhaps involving a "cdef extern" or something similar.

3) Directly call the function **without** having to pass by:

```
import fortran_func

out = fortran_func.foo(x, y)
```

The idea is that I have three for loops around this function call and calling the fortran function through a python import is really slow. Currently I have this:

```
import fortran_func

cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=3] cy_func(double[::1] x,
                                        double[::1] y,
                                        double[::1] z,
                                        int N):
    cdef:
        int i, j, k
        np.ndarray[double, ndim=3] out

    out = np.zeros((N, N, N), dtype=np.float64)

    for i in range(N): # fast C loops
        for j in range(N):
            for k in range(N):
                # extremely slow python call
                out[i,j,k] = fortran_func.foo(x[i], y[j], z[k])

                # would prefer a fast, direct function call
                # out[i,j,k] = foo(x[i], y[j], z[k])
```

I would very much appreciate any help in finding out what this magic step should be!

Comment: I think the process for interfacing with Python at [fortran90.org](http://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html#interfacing-with-python) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a shared fortran object as a c-function with ctypes without converting to python types. You should be able to do so with cython as well. I wrote it down here:

http://pythology.blogspot.fr/2014/03/wrapping-fortran-and-python-without-f2py.html

This is the summary:

fortran file add.f95:

```
subroutine add(a,b,c)    
    implicit none
    integer a,b,c
    c = a + b 
end
```

compile with:

```
gfortran -shared -fPIC add.f95 -o add.so
```

the python code to call it (careful, 'add' becomes 'add_') is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from ctypes import c_int, byref, cdll

a = c_int(3)
b = c_int(4)
c = c_int()

addlib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./add.so')
addlib.add_(byref(a),byref(b),byref(c))
print c
```

Comment: I think it's still going to work though like a python object that just points to some code.  So for cython purposes (I think), it's going to be as slow as the f2py solution...

Comment: if you use ctypes yes, but if you import it directly into cython as an external c-function your python code doesn't even know that its fortran!?